# facebook API from Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, facebook

Does anyone have a sample showing how to query Facebook user photos from Silverlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another one:

[http://community.irritatedvowel.com/blogs/pete_browns_blog/archive/2008/10/16/How-to-Build-Facebook-Applications-with-Silverlight-2-RTW-*1320*-Part-1-of-2.aspx](http://community.irritatedvowel.com/blogs/pete_browns_blog/archive/2008/10/16/How-to-Build-Facebook-Applications-with-Silverlight-2-RTW-_1320_-Part-1-of-2.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the [WPF Facebook example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFacebook.aspx) on CodeProject? Shouldn't be too different from Silverlight.